# Size of Foreign key constraint

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

My googling powers were not strong enough for this one. This is all theoretical question.

Let's say I have a huge database with hundreds of tables and each table has a user column which references user table.

Now if I would change the user column to have a foreign key constraint, would the increase in database size be noticeable?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "*huge*". But yes, the database would increase in size and that would be noticeable. But from being noticeable to being a problem, there is a possibly big difference. The size by which the database would increase depends on the amount of data (number of rows) that you have in your database & tables, not the complexity of the database (hundreds of tables). I believe you can see in SSMS the size an object occupies in your DB, by going to the Object Explorer window, then to your object and right click-ing and going to Properties, but you have to create your FK first.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: that's wrong. Simply defining a _constraint_ does not change the size of the database in any way (except for the few rows added to the system catalogs)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Lesson learned, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "*change the user column to have a foreign key constraint*" you mean something like:

```
alter table some_table
   add constraint fk_some_table_users 
   foreign key (user_id) 
   references users (id);
```

Then the answer is: no, this will in no way change the size of your database (except some additional rows in the system catalogs to store the definition of your constraint).

---

The constraints will improved the reliability of your data and in some cases even might help the optimizer to remove unnecessary joins or take other shortcuts based on the constraint information. There is however a small performance overhead when insert or deleting rows because the constraint needs to be verified. But this small overhead does not outweigh the advantages that you gain from having consistent data in your database.

I have never seen an application which claimed to be able to "have that under control" that didn't need data cleaning after having been in production for some time. So best leave this kind of check to the database.